# Hide CCK fields for users without references with node

Tags: 6, entities, users, taxonomy-terms

I have a role "worker".
I have one content type "task" that can be viewed just by "workers".
"Task" has 3 fields:

1. field-A: a user reference field to select a "worker" user;
2. field-B: one textfield that can be view from any "worker";
3. field-C: one textfield that can be view just from "workers" related to the node using field-A.

How can I set permissions to let users view just the fields they are allowed to?
Content_permission just has a per role granularity, so I can't use it in a dynamic context and with many categories.
User Reference Access just set permission to the whole node.
I'm looking for something like Taxonomy Access, but with a per field granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Field Permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module which allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: This seems to do the same as Content Permission, ported to D7.

Comment: But this allows to manage permissions for each field separately during edit of particular form field..

Comment: Yes, but always on a author/role basis. How do you suggest to solve this?